# What should be done with mezuzot when selling the house?

Tags: halacha, mezuzah

What should be done about the mezuzot (internal and external) when selling one's house...

- to a non-Jew?
- to a non-observant Jew?
- to an observant Jew?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To a non-Jew: take them down.

To a Jew: you're supposed to leave them up, and you can charge him for the cost. . There are differing opinions whether, if you have super-special mezuzas up there, you can replace them with ordinary mezuzahs; what I've heard is mostly that it's permissible. look in אשל אברהם he says you may change it to other kosher not so mehuder

Comment: I understand this to be the _halacha_ also, but a source would be nice.

Comment: @msh210: I don't have access to my references right now. Hopefully coming soon.

Comment: How about now (access to the sources)?

Comment: @msh210 its a gemara in the end of bava metzia and is quoted lehalacha by the shulchan aruch. end of hasocher if i remember correctly.

Comment: This happened to us so I researched this. A source is in Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 11:21 "_If one is moving out of a house and another Jew moves in to live there, the first person may not take the mezuzot off. Rather he should leave them there and the second person should compensate him for their value"_. Unlike what @Shalom writes, the rabbanims I asked said __you cannot take them with you__  if the new resident refuses to pay for them. So CYLOR