# Must One Remove the Mezuzot from a House Rented to Gentiles?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, mezuzah, rental

Is there any obligation to take down your mezuzot if a house you own (and live in some of the time) is rented to Gentiles for an extended period of time (e.g. over 30 days)?

I ask because I recently heard someone doing so, and they were under the impression that this was halachically required, but I have never before heard of this being done. And if this is not required, are there sources who suggest doing such as a best practice, or a chumrah?

Comment: similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9356/759

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Bava Metziah 102a and Shulchan Aruch Hilchos Mezuzah 291:2 that when renting a house to a gentile one removes the mezuzos.

Later authorities debate if this is merely an allowance since the obligation to have them up has ceased, or if this is an obligation due to the concern of the gentile, who sees no value to it, destroying or otherwise harming it. My impression is most modern authorities rule like the latter opinions.

Comment: Schmerel see my edits which, as you described in your comment, better represent the sources you cited. Now the answer is no longer misleading.

Comment: I appreciate these related sources, but neither of them seem to directly support the practice mentioned in my question (where a Jew owns the house, and plans on living there again). Rather, they seem to deal with when a Jewish renter finishes renting and sees that the next renter is an idolater, no?